# Automatically populating dataobjectset with contents of assets subfolder in Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I'm currently working on a Silverstripe 3.1 website that has dozens of random header images.

I can easily setup a "HeaderImage" databobjectset, but manually adding every image via the CMS would be a tedious headache.

Is there a simple way to have a dataobjectset automatically populated by the contents of a folder.

For example every image file in /assets/header-images/ automatically becomes a "HeaderImage" object. I want to be able to easily add or remove images.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can upload multiple images at once using the GridFieldBulkEditingTools module: https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools. It's worth a look.

Comment: @3dgoo solution would work, every image you upload via GridFieldBulkEditingTools will create a DataObject. Best thing is to have it hooked to a ModelAdmin. But if you really want SS to browse folders, a build task might do the job, and if it has to be done often, a CRON...

Comment: @colymba - if you can make an answer with some details I'm more than happy to vote it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some details about the proposed solutions.

**1)** Like **@3dgoo** mentioned, using the GridFieldBulkEditingTools module. Download the latest master of best via composer `"colymba/gridfield-bulk-editing-tools": "dev-master"`. This will let you upload a bunch of images and will create a DataObject for each one. Use the *Bulk upload* button. Here is how to have it set up in `ModelAdmin`:

```
class HeaderAdmin extends ModelAdmin
{
  private static $managed_models = array('HeaderImage');
  private static $url_segment = 'header-admin';
  private static $menu_title = 'Header admin';

  public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null)
  {
    $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);
    $gridField = $form->Fields()->fieldByName($this->sanitiseClassName('HeaderImage'));

    if ( $gridField )
    {
      $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldBulkImageUpload());
    }

    return $form;
  }
}
```

**2)** Another solution, which would require a lot more work, is create a `BuildTask` and sort out the logic in `run()`:

```
class ImportHeaderImagesTask extends BuildTask
{ 
  protected $title = 'Import Header Images';  
  protected $description = 'Import Header Images......';

  /**
   * Check that the user has appropriate permissions to execute this task
   */
  public function init()
  {
    if( !Director::is_cli() && !Director::isDev() && !Permission::check('ADMIN') )
    {
      return Security::permissionFailure();
    }
    parent::init();
  }

  /**
   * Do some stuff
   */
  public function run($request)
  {     
    // this is where files are uploaded manually  
    $TempFTPFolder = ASSETS_PATH . '/FTP';

    // This is the folder where files will be moved  
    $LiveFolderPath = 'assets/path/to/final/live/folder/';
    $LiveFolder = DataObject::get_one('File', "Filename = '$LiveFolderPath'");


    if ( file_exists( $TempFTPFolder ) && $LiveFolder->ID ) // if the FTP upload folder exist and the destination live folder exist
    {
      $FTPList = scandir( $TempFTPFolder ); // get the FTP folder content

      foreach ($FTPList as $FileFolder)
      {
        $FTPFile = $TempFTPFolder . '/' . $FileFolder;
        if ( is_file( $FTPFile ) ) // process files only
        {
          // Create File object for the live version
          $NewFile = new File();
          $NewFile->setParentID( $LiveFolder->ID );
          $NewFile->setName( $FileFolder );

          // get target name/path
          $RenameTarget = $NewFile->getFullPath();

          if ( $RenameTarget )
          {
            $moved = false;
            try {
              $moved = rename( $FTPFile, $RenameTarget ); // move the FTP file to the live folder
            } catch (Exception $e) {}

            if ( $moved )
            {
              $NewFile->write();

              // create DataObject and add image relation
              $HeaderImage = HeaderImage::create();
              $HeaderImage->ImageID = $NewFile->ID;
              $HeaderImage->write();
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

You can run this tasks via the `dev/` url or via the command line or a CRON job. Note that I adapted the `run()` logic from something I've done a while ago, so not guaranteed it will work by just copy/pasting.